# Django/Django Rest Framework - How do I allow model serializer to set model's foreign key field to null?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to be able to set the `borrower` field (a foreign key) in my `Asset` model to be `NULL` but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm trying to send a PATCH request with JSON data that has the key `borrower` equal to value of `NULL`  but the `borrower` field won't get updated to `NULL` for the model instance.  Perhaps there is an issue with the serializer that is preventing the foreign key field from being able to be set to `NULL`?

I have already tried passing in `allow_null=True` to `BorrowSerializer` class but that hasn't worked.  I've searched high and low on StackOverflow for posts with similar problems and solutions but nothing I've tried has worked.

Here is my models.py:

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import date
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

import uuid

class Category(models.Model):
    """Model representing an Asset category"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Borrower(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    associated_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

class Asset(models.Model):
    """Model representing an Asset"""
    # Unique identifier for an instance of an asset (a barcode of sorts)
    uid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(Borrower, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    checked_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    return_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)    

    CONDITION_TYPE = (
        ('e', 'Excellent'),
        ('g', 'Good'),
        ('f', 'Fair'),
        ('p', 'Poor'),
    )

    condition = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=CONDITION_TYPE,
        blank=True,
        help_text='Asset condition')

    class Meta:
            ordering = ['return_date']

    @property
    def is_dueback(self):
        if self.return_date and date.today() > self.return_date:
            return True
        return False

    def display_category(self):
        """Create a string for the Category. This is required to display category in Admin."""
        return ', '.join(category.name for category in self.category.all())

    display_category.short_description = 'Category'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.uid} - {self.name}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('asset-detail', args=[str(self.uid)])
```

Here is my serializers.py file:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from inventory.models import Asset, Borrower, Category

class BorrowerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Borrower
        fields = ('first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'associated_user'
        )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print('Update method triggered.')
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.associated_user = validated_data.get('associated_user'. instance.associated_user)
        instance.save()
        return instance

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'

class AssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    borrower = BorrowerSerializer(allow_null=True)
    category = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    condition = serializers.CharField(source='get_condition_display')

    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        fields = ('name', 
                  'manufacturer', 
                  'model',
                  'description',
                  'condition',
                  'category',
                  'borrower',
                  'checked_out',
                  'return_date',
                  'is_dueback',
        )
```

Here are my DRF API Views:

```py
class AssetRetrieveUpdateDestroy(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'uid'
    serializer_class = AssetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Asset.objects.filter(owner=user)

class BorrowerRetrieveUpdateDestroy(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'id'
    serializer_class = BorrowerSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Borrower.objects.all()
```

I expected the `borrower` field in my `Asset` model instance to be updated to NULL when I pass in this JSON:

```
data = {
   'borrower': null
}
```

However, my model instance won't update the `borrower` field when it's a foreign key. It works fine if the field is `CharField` or something else, but on foreign keys. I printed out the data returned from my AJAX request but the `borrower` field stays unchanged.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations):

> If you're supporting writable nested representations you'll need to write `.create()` or `.update()` methods that handle saving multiple objects.

Thus you need to implement the `.update()` method in your `AssetSerializer`:

```
class AssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    borrower = BorrowerSerializer(allow_null=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        fields = (...)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.borrower = validated_data.get('borrower')
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

This should do the work. So no matter that you've passed `allow_null=True`, it will accept *null values*, but won't update your nested relationship unless you define your custom update mechanism.

Comment: Thank you!  I had to use `validated_data.get()` instead of `validated_data.pop()` for the serializer to update my model instance as desired.  I appreciate your help very much for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @elev8eng Make sure to accept the answer in order to guide further readers to the right direction. :)